# Is it possible to convert a conjunction of two implications into an implication of disjunctions?

Tags: proof-verification, logic

I want to use the following equivalence as part of a proof:

1. $$(P\implies Q ) \land (R \implies S) $$

is equivalent to

2. $$ P \lor R \implies Q \lor S$$?

Intuitively, it makes sense that $1 \implies 2$, but I'm not sure about the other direction ($2 \implies 1$). Is this correct? Why? If it is possible to prove this, which are the steps I'm missing?

Comment: Counterexample: $P,Q,R,S$ respectively true, false, true, true.

Comment: $(P \vee R) \Rightarrow [(Q \wedge \neg R) \vee (Q \wedge S) \vee (\neg P \wedge S)]$ is equivalent to 1.

Comment: Why not write a truth table of the equivalence and see where it gives false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, if you know that
$$P \lor R \implies Q \lor S$$
there is no reason to conclude that
$$P \implies Q \quad\hbox{and}\quad  R \implies S\ .$$
For example, it might be that
$$P \implies S \quad\hbox{and}\quad  R \implies Q\ .$$
So you should not expect that $(2)$ implies $(1)$.  For a more formal solution, see Alexander's answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, $(2)\implies (1)$ is false. The easiest example of that is when $S=P$ and $Q=R=\neg P$. Then $(1)\equiv\bot$ and $(2)\equiv\top$.

Answer (score 0):

Using Implication Equivalence and other boolean algebra gives us

$\begin{split}(p\to q)\land(r\to s) 
&\equiv (\neg p\lor q)\land(\neg r \to s)
\\&\equiv (\neg p\land\neg r)\lor(\neg p\land s)\lor(q \land \neg r)\lor(q\land s)
\\&\equiv \lnot(p\lor r)\lor ((q\wedge(\lnot r\vee s))\vee(s\land(\neg p\vee q)))
\\ &\equiv (p\lor r)\to ((q\land(r\to s))\lor(s\land(p\to q))) 
\end{split}$

Which is clearly not equivalent to $(p\lor r)\to(q\lor s)$